# Integration by Parts for $f\in C^\infty$ and $\phi \in C^\infty_c$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

I am working through Robert Zimmer's Essential Results of Functional Analysis, and I seem to be stuck on a lemma that should be extremely simple: integration by parts.

> Lemma 1.1.16: Suppose $f\in C^\infty (\Omega) $ and $\phi \in C^\infty_c (\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset R^n$ is open.  $\partial_i f$
>   denotes the $i$-th partial derivative of $f$.  Then for any $i$:
>
> $$\int_\Omega f(\partial_i \phi) = - \int_\Omega (\partial_i f) \phi$$
>   (Note that $C^\infty$ is the space of smooth functions, and $C^\infty_c$ is the space of smooth functions with compact support.)

This is not the integration by parts I am used to.  For example, $i=1$, then this is just the standard integration by parts, and it should be:

$$\int_\Omega f(\phi') = f \phi - \int_\Omega (f') \phi$$

Where did the $f\phi$ term go?  If I could understand it for $i=1$, I could then apply it recursively to get $i>1$, but I don't understand how the Lemma was derived.

Comment: You are mixing definite and indefinite integrals in your equation. Fix that and it should be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially it is like that since $\phi$ has compact support over $\Omega$, i.e. $\phi$ vanishes outside of $\Omega$, i.e. in particular $\phi(x)=0$ for all $x \in \partial \Omega$. So when we integrate by parts (in the case $i=1$) we get

$$\int_\Omega f \phi'~dx = \underbrace{\int_{\partial \Omega} f \overbrace{\phi}^{=0} ~ds}_{=0}-\int_\Omega f' \phi ~dx=-\int_\Omega f' \phi ~dx$$

For $i=2,3,...$ it is just the same. One can also see it if we pick the 1D example $\Omega=(a,b)$ then $\phi$ has compact support over $(a,b)$ and therefore we get

$$\int_a^b f \phi'~dx = f \phi~\bigg|_a^b-\int_a^b f' \phi ~dx=f(b)\underbrace{\phi(b)}_{=0}-f(a)\underbrace{\phi(a)}_{=0}-\int_a^b f' \phi ~dx=-\int_\Omega f' \phi ~dx$$